# How to parse .proto file into a FileDescriptor in C#?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

My goal is exactly the same as stated in [this issue on github](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6853):

> how to read an existing .proto file and get a FileDescriptor from it

I cannot use the suggested "workaround", for 2 reasons:

- I have "plain" .proto files, i.e.:

  - they are text files, just like good old [addressbook.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/examples/addressbook.proto)
  - they are not [self-describing](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description)
- I do not want to invoke the protoc compiler as an external application.

[According to Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47635433/11398730) this is possible with [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) library:

> Without a compiled schema, you would need a runtime .proto parser. [...] protobuf-net includes one ([protobuf-net.Reflection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.Reflection/))

I found [`Parsers.cs`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/Parsers.cs)

Thanks Marc, but how do I use/do this?
Is this the right entry point?
Is there a minimal working example somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var set = new FileDescriptorSet();
set.Add("my.proto", true);
set.Process();
```

That's all you need; note that if you want to provide the actual contents (rather than having the library do the file access), there is an optional `TextReader` parameter. If you need imports:

```
set.AddImportPath(...);
```

Once you've called `Process`, the `.Files` should be populated along with the `.MessageTypes` of each file, etc.

For a more complete example:

```
var http = new HttpClient();
var proto = await http.GetStringAsync(
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/master/examples/addressbook.proto");

var fds = new FileDescriptorSet();
fds.Add("addressbook.proto", true, new StringReader(proto));
fds.Process();
var errors = fds.GetErrors();
Console.WriteLine($"Errors: {errors.Length}");

foreach(var file in fds.Files)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);

    foreach (var topLevelMessage in file.MessageTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{topLevelMessage.Name} has {topLevelMessage.Fields.Count} fields");
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
addressbook.proto
Person has 5 fields
AddressBook has 1 fields

google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
Timestamp has 2 fields
```

Notice that you didn't have to provide `timestamp.proto` or an import path for it - the library embeds a number of the common imports, and makes them available automatically.

(each file is a `FileDescriptorProto`; the group of files in a logical parse operation is the `FileDescriptorSet` - which is the root object used from [descriptor.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto); note that all of the objects in this graph are also protobuf serializable, if you need a compiled/binary schema)

Comment: That clarifies a lot. I was fiddling around with `fileDescriptorProto.Parse(new StreamReader("addressbook.proto"), new List<Error>(), null);` meanwhile, which actually works for a single file. Given that none of the two file related parameters is explicitly optional, that signature was a bit confusing to me. Is `Parse()` intentionally public?

Comment: @user11398730 probably not, no; my bad - marked as hidden and obsolete, here: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/commit/7b7f835d653d1e9b29bfafb987d47245296675e5#diff-66411385b26de390f650e973dafe4ab2R839-R844

Comment: I doesn't see .Add method in FileDescriptorSet class. Which assembly/dependency I should use?

Comment: @Anton protobuf-net.Reflection